# Adding values to map in apex inside for each

Tags: apex, map

```
Map<string,string> salesPerCloser {get; set;}
AggregateResult[] closerResults = [SELECT Count(Id), Closer__c from opportunity where ReportRegion__c = 'Brasil' AND CreatedDate =LAST_N_DAYS:7 group by Closer__c]; 
salesPerCloser = new Map<string,string>();    
for(AggregateResult ar : closerResults)
{
    salesPerCloser.put(String.Valueof(ar.get('expr0')),String.Valueof(ar.get('closer__c')));
   system.debug(salesPerCloser); 
}
system.debug(salesPerCloser);
```

> 11:40:07:021 USER_DEBUG [7]|DEBUG|{1=Adriana S}
>
> 11:40:07:021 USER_DEBUG [7]|DEBUG|{1=Alicia Barbel}
>
> 11:40:07:022 USER_DEBUG [7]|DEBUG|{1=Barbora Novotna}
>
> 11:40:07:022 USER_DEBUG [9]|DEBUG|{1=Barbora Novotna}

If i put anothery key value page after loop its gets added correctly. Is there anything i am doing wrong? I am expecting map to have all three values. Instead of just last one. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `Key` in `Map` is same for all the records, it will overwrite the existing records in the `Map` with the same `Key`.

In your case the `Key` for all 3 records is `1` that is the reason, it is showing the latest record in the `Map` in your final `debug`.

You can go through the documentation of [Map](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_map.htm) for further information.

Excerpt from the above mentioned documentation

> - Map keys and values can be of any data type—primitive types,    collections, sObjects, user-defined types, and built-in Apex types.
> - Uniqueness of map keys of user-defined types is determined by the    equals and hashCode methods, which you provide in your classes.
>     Uniqueness of keys of all other non-primitive types, such as sObject
>     keys, is determined by comparing the objects’ field values.
> - Map keys of type String are case-sensitive. Two keys that differ only    by the case are considered unique and have corresponding
>     distinct Map    entries. Subsequently, the Map methods, including put,
>     get,    containsKey, and remove treat these keys as distinct.
>
> **put(key, value)**
>
> > If the map previously contained a mapping for this key, the old value
> >     is returned by the method and then replaced.
> >
> > If the key is a string, the key value is case-sensitive.

```
Map<String, String> colorCodes = new Map<String, String>();

colorCodes.put('Red', 'ff0000');
colorCodes.put('Red', '#FF0000');
// Red is now #FF0000
```

Similarly, in your case, something like below is happenning

```
salesPerCloser.put('1','Adriana S');
salesPerCloser.put('1','Alicia Barbel');
salesPerCloser.put('1','Barbora Novotna');
//1 is now Barbora Novotna
```

When using `Maps`, make sure you have key as unique otherwise it will override the existing values, in your case, you can switch the key value pair depending on your requirement i.e.

Replace

```
salesPerCloser.put(String.Valueof(ar.get('expr0')),String.Valueof(ar.get('closer__c')));
```

with

```
salesPerCloser.put(String.Valueof(ar.get('closer__c')), String.Valueof(ar.get('expr0')));
```

so that it gives you the count of records for each `Closer__c`

Comment: sorry it was stupid question.

Comment: No problem, it does happen sometimes :)